# Problem while converting Python code to exe via cx_freeze

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a very simple code to exe. Code utilizes Kivy as follows;

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

#from kivy import Config
#Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    
    def press(self, var_ex):

        name = self.ids.name_input.text
        self.ids.name_label.text = f"Hello {name} !" * var_ex


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return MyLayout()


if __name__.endswith('__main__'):from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""

<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 20
        padding: 50

        Button:
            text: "English"

        Button:
            text: "Italian"
            size_hint: ( None, None)
            width: 100
            height: 50
            pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.5}

        Button:
            text: "German"
            size_hint: ( 0.5, 0.5)

""")


class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This code works very well in python, with no errors. But when I try to convert it to exe via this setup.py file and cx_freeze;

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["kivy","pygame","kivy_deps.gstreamer"], "includes": ["kivy_deps.glew","kivy_deps.sdl2","wheel","setuptools","pygments","docutils","win32api","PIL"], "excludes": []}

#base = ""
base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name="guifoo",
    version="0.1",
    description="My GUI application!",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("test.py", base=base)],
)
```

I get following error when running the created exe file (exe file is created without error);

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Python310\kivy_venv\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 113, in run
     module_init.run(name + "__main__")
   File "D:\Python310\kivy_venv\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 15, in run
     exec(code, module_main.__dict__)
   File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
   File "D:\Python310\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py", line 317, in <module>
     mod = importer.find_module(modname).load_module(modname)
   File "D:\Python310\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy_deps\glew\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
     p = join(d, 'share', 'glew', 'bin')
   File "D:\Python310\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join
     path = os.fspath(path)
 TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Can somebody help me on this ?
Thanks in advance...

P.S. I can give more information if requested.

Comment: is `test.py` the name of your script?

Comment: Yes, that is the name of the python code file I am trying to convert to exe.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I still cannot figure out what the problem is with cx_freeze but, I was able to get it to work with PyInstaller.  These are the steps I took.

```
pip install pyinstaller
cp test.py test
```

Inside the `test` file I had to remove both `if __name__ ==`  lines like below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

#from kivy import Config
#Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    
    def press(self, var_ex):

        name = self.ids.name_input.text
        self.ids.name_label.text = f"Hello {name} !" * var_ex


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return MyLayout()


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""

<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 20
        padding: 50

        Button:
            text: "English"

        Button:
            text: "Italian"
            size_hint: ( None, None)
            width: 100
            height: 50
            pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.5}

        Button:
            text: "German"
            size_hint: ( 0.5, 0.5)

""")


class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


MyApp().run()
```

Then

```
pyinstaller -F --noconsole test
```

which will create the executable in the `dist` directory.  I tested and this works. I still don't know why cx_freeze won't work though.

Comment: I once again followed these steps (although I did them before several times) "exactly" but I get the same error. My system is Windows 11 and Python is installed in drive D. Can these make any difference ? I updated my screen card drivers just to be sure but nothing changed. Also my IDE is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @BlueHawk77 All of my information is the same except for the drive D part... I doubt that is the issue but let me check it out.

Comment: This is the graphics part of my config.ini file at users\username\.kivi folder `[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0
vsync = 
verify_gl_main_thread = 1
custom_titlebar = 0
custom_titlebar_border = 5` Do you see any difference with yours ?

Comment: Especially at multisamples part

Comment: @BlueHawk77  It ran fine on my d drive too.  I added my pip freeze results make sure yours match.  I don't think the problem is with your graphics based on the error message you are getting

Comment: @BlueHawk77  Yah I just checked and my graphics numbers are identical.

Comment: Can this be anything related with path values ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244926/discussion-between-bluehawk77-and-alexpdev).

Comment: Finally I switched to pyinstaller but for pyinstaller I have another question regarding excluding modules. I'll be glad if you can help me there...

Comment: @BlueHawk77 Sure Ill go back into the chat room.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to convert your program into a .exe, I would suggest using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/). You can easily install it using the command `pip install pyinstaller` in the command line. And there is no need for any setup.py file as well.

After installing it, simply navigate to the directory of the file you want to convert to an .exe (lets call this `myFile.py`) and type the following in the command line:

```
pyinstaller myFile.py
```

This will create a few things in that directory:

1. a file called `myFile.spec`
2. a folder called `build`
3. a folder called `dist`

The only important thing out of these is the `dist` folder. Inside it, you will find an .exe of your python script that you can run as an .exe. However, if you are importing files from directories that are relative to your `myFile.py` that are needed to run the `.py` script, simply move the `myFile.exe` to the same directory as `myFile.py` and it will work.

There are also additional arguments that you can add when converting to .exe that you can see on the pyinstaller website (i.e, you can remove the console from appearing when running the .exe by adding `--noconsole` to the end of the command).

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Protolaser for your answer. I am new to Python but pyinstaller was the first option I tried before cx_freeze. At pyinstaller I found it rather difficult to select which modules I want to be included in my compiled exe and size of the exe files also seemed too big. So I decided to try cx_freeze. I have read somewhere that it has more flexibility on selection of modules and configuration of compiling process. Is it wrong and pyinstaller is better ?

Comment: Pyinstaller is better because it is multiplatform (works for IOS and Windows) and it does not require any setup files. You simply need to specify the .py file that you want to turn into an .exe and it does it for you.

Comment: Finally I switched to pyinstaller but for pyinstaller I have another question regarding excluding modules. I'll be glad if you can help me there...